# Getting Nhibernate ISession from Controller (Session Per Request) ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

I have seen many posts of how to setup a session per request in Asp.Net MVC by using ActionFilter or by a DI package to inject the session into the controller. What I wanted to know was, will it be a bad idea/pattern to just make an extension method like :

```
public static ISession GetNHibernateSession(this Controller controller)
 {
   return SessionFactory.OpenSession();
 }
```

so that the session can be instantiated when required like :

```
public ActionResult DoSomething()
    {
      using(  var session = this.GetNHibernateSession())
        {
           // Do something with the session
        }

    }
```

reasons why this may be a good/bad idea will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good:

- It's simple
- It just works

Bad:

- You are doing session management, even if it's just a three lines, all over your code
- With an extension method, you can't replace the behavior for testing

In short, for small, RAD and proof-of-concept projects, your idea will work just fine. For more complex development, it's probably better to extract session management from the controllers, at least moving it to a base class.